# Oracle parents key not found

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Im trying to add a constraint to a reservation table, the reservation can either be for a flight or accommodation or both.

[image: Reservation]

- First 4 records booked inward flight, outward flight and accommodation
- Next 4 records booked a flight only and have `acc_id` set to `NULL`
- Following 2 records booked only accommodation, hence in flight, out flight and seats are set to null.

Here are my constraints for this table

```
ALTER TABLE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT HOLIDAY_PK PRIMARY KEY (RESV_ID);
ALTER TABLE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_FK FOREIGN KEY (BOOKING_CUS_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUS_ID);
ALTER TABLE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT STAFF_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES STAFF (EMP_ID);
ALTER TABLE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_FK FOREIGN KEY (IN_FLIGHT_ID) REFERENCES FLIGHT (FLI_ID);
ALTER TABLE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (OUT_FLIGHT_ID) REFERENCES FLIGHT (FLI_ID);
ALTER TABLE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT ACC_FK FOREIGN KEY (ACC_ID) REFERENCES ACCOMMODATION (ACC_ID);
```

and the only constraint that is yielding an error is;

```
ALTER TABLE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (OUT_FLIGHT_ID) REFERENCES FLIGHT (FLI_ID);
```

I get

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02298: cannot validate (U1146815.FLIGHT_FK1) - parent keys not found
```

What seems to be the problem? i understand that it has to do with orphan childs, but i am setting nulls so i dont understand, please advise

Comment: according to your screenshot OUT_FLIGHT_ID contains some data (not only nulls) are you sure all of these OUT_FLIGHT_IDs are FLI_IDs in FLIGHT table ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, i forgot to insert the other half of the records :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error indicates that the `FLIGHT` table does not have an entry for at least one of the `FLI_ID` values between 11 and 18.  You'd need to insert a row in the `FLIGHT` table for whatever flights are missing or update your table to have a different `OUT_FLIGHT_ID`.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I just realized i generated the other half of the flight table and forgot to insert it to the database :)

Answer (score 3):

Delete all the rows from the child table which is being used to alter the column for having the references.

```
ALTER TABLE sales ADD CONSTRAINT sales_time_fk
FOREIGN KEY (time_id) REFERENCES times (time_id) 
RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Comment: good point, @Mohammad Shahnawaz,... i never realized that . :D